# Building GCC 11.2 on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, gcc, amazon-workspaces

While attempting to build GCC version 11.3 for Linux-x86_64 (with multilib and multiarch support enabled), I am getting the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:447,
                 from /usr/include/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:27,
                 from /home/slagathor/Developer/gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:87,
                 from /home/slagathor/Developer/gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/generic-morestack.c:32:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:11: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
    7 | # include <gnu/stubs-32.h>
```

From what I can tell this means that I don't have glibc-devel (32-bit version) installed; however when attempting to install it via YUM I get the following output:

```
$ sudo yum install glibc-devel.i686              

Loaded plugins: amzn_workspaces_filter_updates, halt_os_update_check, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                                             | 3.7 kB  00:00:00     
firefox                                                                                                                                | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
workspaces-internal-dependencies                                                                                                       | 2.2 kB  00:00:00     
No package glibc-devel.i686 available.
```

I am using an Amazon Linux Workspace, any assistance would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are using centos so you need to go to chrome and search for "How to install glibc-devel.i686 for centos".

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. To post comments earn 50 reputation, here is a link on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation